# Show div if another div has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I don't get why this isn't working. I want to show a Div when another div has a value. I got this code from stackoverflow and it's pretty simple. But it doesn't work for me. No console errors..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".txt").html().length > 0) {
     $('.btn-01').show();
   }                                           
 });
```

If the html value of `.txt` is larger then 0 then show `btn-01`.

But it doesn't. In my web inspector it just says:

```
<div style="display: block;" class="btn-01"><p>Things</p></div>
```

If I remove the script it says:

```
<div class="btn-01"><p>Things</p></div>
```

So it does do something. I tried changing the `show` to `hide`. But no go.

```
<div style="display: none;" class="btn-01"><p>Things</p></div>
```

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(".txt").html().length > 0) {
         $('.btn-01').addClass('showme);
       }                                           
     });
```

btn-01 css:

```
.btn-01 {
    background: #f60;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

But that didn't work either. Does anyone know whats going on here?
Maybe I should work with an `else` statement? Help would be much appreciated.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s912wxy/)

Comment: How does a div have a value?

Comment: Changed the subject.

Comment: Why not use `$(".txt").text() != "")` ?

Comment: So what is the length? `console.log("I found:", $(".txt").html().length);` is it actually giving you a length greater than zero?

Comment: Your script is working. You see the `style="display: block;"` and `style="display: none;"`. What do you want else?

Comment: @epascarello yeah. **$(".txt").html().length** will return value. It will convert everything inside that div into string and return the no. of strings. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/oz3vz8cb/)

Comment: So it is giving you a number greater than zero?

Comment: what is your btn-01 css

Comment: I found: 15 @epascarello

I want the button to show or hide, that isn't happening

Comment: Go with .css('visibility', 'visible') and 'hidden'.

Comment: when you say it "doesn't work" what exactly do you mean?  can you include the original css for the `btn-01` div - is it hidden before you show it?  How do you hide it?  If you use `visibility:hidden` then your code won't work

Comment: see update @orangespark

Comment: @Steggie it is happening, like you see style="display: block;" and style="display: none;". There is something else wrong then. Add you css or even better, create a fiddle!

Comment: how are you hiding this btn-01

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m8Lq8m4y/ <-- works so what is different?

Comment: inspect element on btn-01 and tell me the styles on it

Comment: Im not but i tried adding `display:none` to `btn-01` but that didn't help

Comment: And you verify it is finding the button element? `console.log($('.btn-01'));` Just trying to make sure it is not something simple.

Comment: You answered your own question. You should work with an else statement if you haven't set the style to initially be display:none. That won't account for whitespaces in the div block though. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set the button to display none prior to the window loading or add an "else" statement to hide the element:

```
.btn-01{
  display:none;
}
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(".txt").html().length > 0) {
         $('.btn-01').show();
       }
       else
       {
         $('.btn-01').hide();
       }
     });
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r89gg7tp/

**IMPORTANT TO CONSIDER**

If you have entered a line break between the starting and closing tags of the element, this will add to the length. You need to set the `txt` div to be in the following format:

`<div class='txt'></div>`

It may be better to change your function to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(".txt").html().trim(' ').length > 0) {
         $('.btn-01').show();
       } else {
         $('.btn-01').hide();
       }
     });
```

This way you trim the whitespace before checking.

See the second fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r89gg7tp/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the btn-01 with a "display:none" in the stylesheet and then execute your script.
I think you are having a "display:none !important" which is overriding the jquery show() function inline style.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       if (!$.trim($(".txt").html())){
           $('.btn-01').addClass('showme');
       }                                           
 });
```

Please let me know if you've any queries.

Comment: That will just always add the class `showme` to the btn and not if it has `> 0` content

Comment: It's checking that if the html is not empty then only it will add that class.

Comment: I think the above code will show the btn-01 when the HTML is not available, if you want to check that if the html is available then show btn-01 then you've to remove the ! from condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents()` with `.toggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-01').toggle($(".txt").contents().length > 0);
});
```

```css
.btn-01{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="txt">
  <h3>Things Title</h3>
</div>

<div class="btn-01">
  <p>Things</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys where all right. I needed to place the code in some Session file (Ajax). Now its working with the original code and even some that you provide.

Thanks!